# Binomial Harmonic Numbers

Tags: binomial-coefficients, harmonic-numbers

Prove this equation for $0 \leq m \leq n$:
$$
\frac{1}{\binom{n}{m}}\sum_{k=1}^m \binom{n-k}{n-m} \frac{1}{k} = H_n - H_{n-m}
$$
where $H_k$ denotes the k-th harmonic number $\left(~H_k := \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n}~\right)$.

Tried to use Abels partial summation $\big(\sum_{k=1}^m a_k b_k = a_m \sum_{k=1}^m - \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} (a_{k+1}-a_k)\sum_{i=1}^k b_i \big)$, but it leads to nowhere.

Comment: That can't be right because the LHS depends on $k$ and the RHS doesn't.

Comment: Fixed the typo, ofc k is not bound and free at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prove by Induction:

Base Case: n=0
0 = 0  $\checkmark$

Induction Step:
$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{1}{\binom{n+1}{m}} \sum_{k=1}^m \binom{n+1-k}{n+1-m} \frac{1}{k} &=& \frac{1}{\binom{n+1}{m}} \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{n+1-k}{n+1-m} \binom{n-k}{n-m} \frac{1}{k} \\
&=& \frac{1}{\binom{n+1}{m}} \frac{1}{n+1-m} \sum_{k=1}^m (n+1-k) \binom{n-k}{n-m} \frac{1}{k}  \\
&=& \frac{1}{\binom{n+1}{m}} \frac{1}{n+1-m} \Big[ \sum_{k=1}^m (n+1) \binom{n-k}{n-m} \frac{1}{k} -\sum_{k=1}^m \binom{n-k}{n-m} \Big] \\
&=& \frac{1}{\binom{n+1}{m}} \frac{n+1}{n+1-m}  \sum_{k=1}^m \binom{n-k}{n-m} \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{\binom{n+1}{m}} \frac{1}{n+1-m} \sum_{k=1}^m \binom{n-k}{n-m} \\
&=& H_n - H_{n-m} - \frac{1}{\binom{n+1}{m}} \frac{1}{n+1-m} \frac{n \binom{n-1}{n-m}}{n+1-m} \\ 
&=& H_n - H_{n-m} - \frac{m}{(n+1)(n+1-m)} \\
&=& H_n - H_{n-m} + \frac{-m+(n+1)-(n+1)}{(n+1)(n+1-m)} \\
&=& H_n - H_{n-m} + \frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1-m} \\
&=& \bbx{H_{n+1} - H_{n+1-m}}
\end{eqnarray*}$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{{1 \over {n \choose m}}\sum_{k = 1}^{m}{n - k \choose n - m}{1 \over k} = H_{n} - H_{n - m}:\ {\Large ?}.\quad H_{z}}$ is a *Harmonic Number*.
>   $\ds{\quad0 \leq m \leq n}$.

\begin{align}
{1 \over {n \choose m}}\sum_{k = 1}^{m}{n - k \choose n - m}{1 \over k} & =
{1 \over {n \choose m}}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{n - k \choose m - k}{1 \over k} =
{1 \over {n \choose m}}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{m - n - 1 \choose m - k}
\pars{-1}^{m - k}\,{1 \over k}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pars{-1}^{m} \over {n \choose m}}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}
\braces{\bracks{z^{m - k}}\pars{1 + z}^{m - n - 1}}
\pars{-1}^{k}\int_{0}^{1}t^{k - 1}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
{\pars{-1}^{m} \over {n \choose m}}\bracks{z^{m}}
\pars{1 + z}^{m - n - 1}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-tz}^{k}
\,{\dd t \over t}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pars{-1}^{m} \over {n \choose m}}\bracks{z^{m}}
\pars{1 + z}^{m - n - 1}\int_{0}^{1}{-tz \over 1 + tz}\,{\dd t \over t}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pars{-1}^{m + 1} \over {n \choose m}}\bracks{z^{m}}
\pars{1 + z}^{m - n - 1}\ln\pars{1 + z}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pars{-1}^{m + 1} \over {n \choose m}}
\left.\partiald{}{\epsilon}\bracks{z^{m}}
\pars{1 + z}^{m - n - 1 + \epsilon}\,\right\vert_{\ \epsilon\ =\ 0}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pars{-1}^{m + 1} \over {n \choose m}}
\left.\partiald{}{\epsilon}{m - n - 1 + \epsilon \choose m}
\,\right\vert_{\ \epsilon\ =\ 0}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pars{-1}^{m + 1} \over {n \choose m}}
\left.\partiald{}{\epsilon}{n - \epsilon \choose m}\pars{-1}^{m}
\,\right\vert_{\ \epsilon\ =\ 0}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pars{-1}^{m + 1} \over {n \choose m}}\braces{-{n - \epsilon \choose m}
\bracks{H_{n - \epsilon} - H_{n - m - \epsilon}}\pars{-1}^{m}}
_{\ \epsilon\ =\ 0}
\\[5mm] &=
\bbx{H_{n} - H_{n - m}}
\end{align}

Comment: This is awesome.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks. Maybe, we can cut some unnecessary steps.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is similar to an inductive proof with respect to $m$.

Let the sum of interest be

$$s_{n,m}=\frac{1}{\binom{n}{m}} \sum _{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k} \binom{n-k}{n-m}$$

For $m=1$ we find

$$s_{n,1}=\frac{1}{n}$$

The difference of $s$ with respect to $m$ turns out to be surprisingly simple:

$$s_{n,{m+1}}-s_{n,m}=\frac{1}{n-m}\tag{1}$$

so that

$$s_{n,2}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n-1}$$
$$s_{n,3}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n-2}$$
$$...$$
$$s_{n,m}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n-2}+...+\frac{1}{n-m+1}$$

The last expression is easily identified as the difference between two harmonic numbers. Hence

$$s_{n,m}=H_{n}-H_{n-m}$$

as requested.

And now we prove the recurence relation (1) using the definition

$$\binom{n}{m}=\frac{n!}{m!\;(n-m)!}$$

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
\begin{eqnarray*}
s_{n,{m+1}}-s_{n,m} 
&=& \frac{1}{\binom{n}{m+1}} \sum_{k=1}^{m+1} \frac{1}{k}\binom{n-k}{n-m-1} - \frac{1}{\binom{n}{m}} \sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{k}\binom{n-k}{n-m}\\
&=& \frac{1}{\binom{n}{m}}\left( \frac{m+1}{n-m}\left( \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k} \binom{n-k}{n-m-1} +\frac{1}{m+1}\right) -\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k} \binom{n-k}{n-m}\right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{\binom{n}{m}}\left( \frac{1}{n-m}+ \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k}\binom{n-k}{n-m} \left( \frac{m+1}{m+1-k} -1 \right) \right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{\binom{n}{m}}\left( \frac{1}{n-m}+ \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{m+1-k}\binom{n-k}{n-m} \right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{n-m}\frac{1}{\binom{n}{m}}\left( 1+\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{n-m}{m+1-k}\binom{n-k}{n-m} \right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{n-m}\frac{1}{\binom{n}{m}}\left( 1+\sum_{k=1}^m \binom{n-k}{m-k+1} \right) =\frac{1}{n-m} \\
\end{eqnarray*}$

In the last step we have used the identity

$\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{n}{m}
&=&  \sum_{k=1}^m \binom{n-k}{m-k+1} +1 = \sum_{k=1}^{m+1} \binom{n-k}{m-k+1} \\
\end{eqnarray*}$

which in turn results from iterating the basic recursion of the binomial coefficients

$\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{n}{m}
&=& \binom{n-1}{m}+\binom{n-1}{m-1} \\
&=& \binom{n-1}{m}+\binom{n-2}{m-1}+\binom{n-2}{m-2} \\
&=& \binom{n-1}{m}+\binom{n-2}{m-1}+...+\binom{n-m}{1} +\binom{n-m-1}{0}\tag{2}\\
\end{eqnarray*}$

This completes the proof of (1) and hence the solution.

**Comments**

1) I feel that a much shorter proof should be possible starting from (2), but I didn't find it.

2) Interesting related formula ([Derivative of binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2674183/derivative-of-binomial-coefficients))

$$\frac{d}{dn}\ln\binom{n}{k} = H_{n} - H_{n-k}$$