# Derivative of binomial distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, binomial-distribution

Consider the function $$B(M) = LM-I\cdot\sum_{x=n+1}^{M}{ M \choose x}p^x(1-p)^{M-x}(x-n)$$

What is the first derivative of $B(M)$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2674183/derivative-of-binomial-coefficients) the binomial coefficient is differentiated. Have a look and give a reply.