# Is this sequence increasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Consider the sequence

$\binom n k /n^k$

where k is a number from $0$ to $n$. I want to prove that this sequence is increasing in $n$. It doesn't have to be strictly increasing since for $k = 0,1$ the sequence is constant. Increasing is enough.

I tried to used Bernoulli inequality among others but I can't prove it.

Thank you for any help.

Increasing with respect to n I.e as n increases or with respect to k I.e as increases.

Comment: I might take a logarithm and apply https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2674183/derivative-of-binomial-coefficients .

Answer (score 2):

Try to write it as the product of $k$ fractions, each one is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\binom n k /n^k  > \binom {n-1}k /(n-1)^k 
\\\Leftrightarrow\\
\frac n {n-k}\binom {n-1} k /n^k  > \binom {n-1}k /(n-1)^k
\\\Leftrightarrow\\
\frac n {n-k}/n^k  > 1/(n-1)^k
\\\Leftrightarrow\\
\frac n {n-k}  > \left (\frac n{n-1}\right)^k
$$
Now fix $k$. For $n=k$ the inequality  holds.

All that's left to show is that the slope of the LHS is bigger than that of the RHS once the LHS is bigger than the RHS.